# How copying to the catalog file without extension - only after the name itself

Tags: python, file, copy

I wonder how I can copy files only by name.
E.g:
I have

> *file.png*, *file2222.png*, *file.jpeg*, *file.jpg*, *file.txt*

I can use:

```
for f in files:    
shutil.copy(f, dest)
```

But I must also provide an extension, because now the computer does not understand what the file is. It must have a given file_name.file_extension.

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '...path/file1'

I can improve:

```
for f in files:    
shutil.copy(f + '.txt', dest)
```

How can I copy all files 'file.*' with different extensions?

Comment: Is the file name changing?

Comment: Works fine for me when `dest` only *contains* a string of the destination folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `listdir` and `isfile` from `os` module to list all files in a folder:

Code:

```
import os
import shutil

dir = '.'
# get content of the dir
content = os.listdir(dir)
# get only files in dir. file names will be with extensions
list_of_files = [i for i in content if os.path.isfile(i)]

# copy files to new destination
dest = 'dest'  # for example
for file in list_of_files:    
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(dir, file), os.path.join(dest, file))
```